# how to create associative array from sql table

Tags: php, sql

this is my code

```
include('connect.php');
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$all = mysql_fetch_array($prod);
```

and i wont create associative array look like this

```
$product_array = array(
   '1' =>array('product_id'=>$all['pid'], 'product_name'=>$all['pname'],'product_desc'=>$all['pdesc'], 'product_price'=>$all['pprice'], 'product_img'=>$all['pimage']),
);
```

can you help me ? thanks !

Comment: I'm sure you will be told that you shouldn't use those functions (and you can read that for yourself in the manual also), but since I hope that you are just trying to learn you can read about this function http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc as it is pretty similar to the one you are using, mysql_fetch_array, but it fetches an associative array

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? It looks like it should work. It seems strange that you aren't using a loop to fetch all the rows of the results. If you're only interested in the first row of results, you should use `LIMIT 1` in the query to avoid sending back extra data.

Comment: @mishu `mysql_fetch_array` also returns an associative array. Its result has both numeric and associative elements.

Comment: @Barmar my script dont working becouse i have 10 rows for eg. in table but in $product_array only first. sorry for my English .. )

Comment: The question says that that's what you want it to look like. If that's not what you want, you should say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mysql_*` its deprecated, so use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Given example here:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all errors
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display errors
$conn = mysqli_connect('host name','user name','password','database name');//database connection code
$product_data = array(); // create an empty array
if($conn){
 $prod = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products");
    while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($prod)) {
        $product_data[] = array('product_id'=>$all['pid'], 'product_name'=>$all['pname'],'product_desc'=>$all['pdesc'], 'product_price'=>$all['pprice'], 'product_img'=>$all['pimage']); // assignment
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($product_data); // print product_data array
}else{
  echo mysqli_connect_error(); // show what problem occur in database connectivity
}
mysqli_close($conn); // close the connection
?>
```

Comment: for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
          echo "Thank you very  very very much !!!!!!!!!!!!","<br>";
     }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the results from the query, you need to call `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop and push each row onto the array.

```
$product_array = array();
while ($all = mysql_fetch_array($prod)) {
    $product_array[] = array('product_id'=>$all['pid'], 'product_name'=>$all['pname'],'product_desc'=>$all['pdesc'], 'product_price'=>$all['pprice'], 'product_img'=>$all['pimage']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call mysql_fetch_assoc() function to do it

```
include('connect.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product_id,
                            product_name,
                            product_desc,
                            product_price,
                            product_img
                      FROM products");
$prod = mysql_query($sql);
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($prod)){
    $product_array[] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for your desired output:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$all = mysql_fetch_array($prod);
$allCount   =   count($all);
$product_array  =   array();

if($allCount)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$allCount; $i++)
    {
      $product_array[$i]['product_id']   =   $all[$i]['pid'];
      $product_array[$i]['product_name']  =   $all[$i]['pname'];
      $product_array[$i]['product_desc']  =   $all[$i]['pdesc'];
      $product_array[$i]['product_price'] =   $all[$i]['pprice'];
      $product_array[$i]['product_img']   =   $all[$i]['pimage'];   
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($product_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `$all` just contains one row of results. Why are you using it as a 2-dimensional array?