# Creating an associative array to query one SQL in PHP to get several results

Tags: php, sql

I am new to PHP and would appreciate any assistance in creating an associative array to query a table using SQL.

I want to use one select statement to get multiple results depending on the 'WHERE' key.

```
$a = $DB->getOne("SELECT DEF_VAL FROM JDEFAULTS WHERE DEF_KEY = :0", array('ip'));

$stmt1 = $DB->getOne("SELECT DEF_VAL FROM JDEFAULTS WHERE DEF_KEY = :0", array('ftpUserid'));

$c = $DB->getOne("SELECT DEF_VAL FROM JDEFAULTS WHERE DEF_KEY = :0", array('ftpPasswd'));
```

These codes return different values (as expected). I want to merge all of these into one line of SQL and get the values in a list depending on the DEF_KEY value.

[how to create associative array from sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357092/how-to-create-associative-array-from-sql-table)

I have tried following the solutions from this but haven't been able to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Hashibul Hussain i havent understand your questions completly, but as far as i understood you want one query with three conditions. you can try this. this may work.

`$stmt1 = $DB->getOne("SELECT DEF_VAL FROM JDEFAULTS WHERE DEF_KEY = :0 or WHERE DEF_KEY = :0 or WHERE DEF_KEY = :0",  array('ip'), array('ftpUserid'), array('ftpPasswd'));`

please elabrate your question further so that i can come up with better solution.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. Yep something similar to that. Basically have one SQL query to retrieve three values depending on the condition (using associative arrays or any other best practices). 

I have tried to run your code but got boolean (False) as an output. Can you kindly help me to understand how I can retrieve the strings instead?